# Generic dispatching in a package after a call to devtools::test()

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I am confused about something. when I put this function into a package

```
oddTranspose <- function(x) {
  t(x)
}
```

it works fine

```
m <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0), nrow=2)
M <- as(m, "Matrix")

oddTranspose(m) # works
oddTranspose(M) # works
```

but then, when I use devtools::test(), it stops working

```
devtools::test()
oddTranspose(m) # works
oddTranspose(M)
## t.default(x) : argument is not a matrix
```

This is problematic for me because I test my packages with the following work flow:

build the package, putting a file called

package_root\tests\testthat_tests.R, with the body

```
require(testthat)
require(myPackage)
test_check('myPackage')
```

and then in

package_root\tests\testthat\file.R, I put tests

I then test them in R with

```
library(testthat)
setwd("package_root/tests")
devtools::test()
```

what can I do?

Note that I spared you all of the text of my package overhead but the package's NAMESPACE imports the Matrix package and exports oddTranspose, and that the package DESCRIPTION "depends" on Matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What resolved this was (1) moving all setGeneric calls to all.R (or an early to load .R file) and (2) moving all setMethod calls to inside of the file where the function is.